# React Native get only one cookie despite of sending multiple cookies from Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, cookies

I've problems to get cookies

### Spring

Spring boot is sending mutiple cookies, By using below

```
    import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    @RestController
    public class SampleController {
        @PostMapping("/test")
        public Object test(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
            String cookie1 = "first";
            String cookie2 = "second";
            Cookie firstCookie = new Cookie("uid", cookie1);
            firstCookie.setPath("/");
            firstCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            Cookie secondCookie = new Cookie("token", cookie2);
            secondCookie.setPath("/");
            secondCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
            response.addCookie(firstCookie);
            response.addCookie(secondCookie);
        }
    }
```

### ReactNative

Sending response with two cookies,
and below react native code sample to catch cookie

```
    function test() {
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                credentials: 'include',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            for (const [name, value] of response.headers) {
                if (name === "set-cookie") {
                    console.log(value)
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

i checked cookies with response.header, but i've got last added one ( second - cookie2)

[React debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ludFZ.png)

and i tried also python, postman, i can see three cookies include jsession
[Postman Cookie View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLuMA.png)

how can i get two cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **axios** for the fetch request

```
import axios from 'axios';

// ...

let res = await axios.get(url)
console.log( res.headers["set-cookie"]) 

// or 

axios.get(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.headers["set-cookie"]);
  });
```